# NSArray into NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an NSArray, made up of other NSArrays. Below is the structure.

```
array (
   subArray1 (
       type_1_item1,
       type_2_item2,
       type_3_item3
   ),
   subArray2 (
       type_1_item4,
       type_2_item5,
       type_3_item6
   ),
   subArray3 (
       type_1_item7,
       type_2_item8,
       type_3_item9
   )
)
```

I want to modify the structure, so it is instead an array made up of dictionaries; so the structure would be as so.

```
array (
    dictionary1 {
        type_1 : item1,
        type_2 : item4,
        type_3 : item7
    },
    dictionary2 {
        type_1 : item2,
        type_2 : item5,
        type_3 : item8
    },
    dictionary3 {
        type_1 : item3,
        type_2 : item6,
        type_3 : item9
    }
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < [[array objectAtIndex:i] count]; j++) {

            NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

            if (i == 0) {
                [tempDictionary setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j] forKey:@"type_1"];
            }
            else if (i == 1) {
                [tempDictionary setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j] forKey:@"type_2"];
            }
            else if (i == 2) {
                [tempDictionary setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j] forKey:@"type_3"];
              }
            else if (i == 3) {
                [tempDictionary setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j] forKey:@"type_4"];
            }
            else if (i == 4) {
                [tempDictionary setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j] forKey:@"type_5"];
            }
            else if (i == 5) {
                [tempDictionary setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j] forKey:@"type_6"];
            }
            else if (i == 6) {
                [tempDictionary setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j] forKey:@"type_7"];
            }
            else if (i == 7) {
                [tempDictionary setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j] forKey:@"type_8"];
            }
            else if (i == 8) {
                [tempDictionary setObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j] forKey:@"type_9"];
            }

            [storage addObject:tempDictionary];
        }
    }
```

And this is what is prints out:

```
    {
    type_1 = item1;
},
    {
    type_1 = item4;
},
    {
    type_1 = item7;
},
    {
    type_2 = item2;
},
    {
    type_2 = item5;
},
    {
    type_2 = item8;
},
    {
    type_3 = item3;
},
    {
    type_3 = item6;
}
    {
    type_3 = item9;
}
```

)

Comment: You need to show what you've tried and explain what it does wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I'll do that now.

Comment: Is your goal to simply generate the new structure from scratch or to convert an existing array in the original structure into the new structure?

Comment: I am aiming to convert the existing array into the new structure.

Comment: You're creating a new dictionary for every inner iteration.  I think you probably mean to create a dictionary only every outer iteration.

Comment: And you can simplify the code a lot by using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"type_%d", i]` to generate your key value.

Comment: Yes,that's what I meant.
The 'type_x' is just an example. In the actual project each key will be a specific name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (NSArray *subArray in array) {
   NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
   int counter = 1;
   for (id item in subArray) {
       [dict setObject:item forKey:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"type_%d", counter++]];
   }
   [newArray addObject:dict];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *newBigArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:originalBigArray.count];
for (NSArray *originalSmallArray in originalBigArray)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *newSmallDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:originalBigArray.count];
    for (int x = 0; x < originalSmallArray.count; x++)
    {
        NSString *itemName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"type_%i",x+1];
        [newSmallDictionary setObject:[originalSmallArray objectAtIndex:x] forKey:itemName];
    }
    [newBigArray addObject:newSmallDictionary];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Loop through the array with a counter and set each element with a key made of the counter.
[@(counter) stringValue] for instance

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: No need, there are already good exampels in the other answers. Thanks for downvoting a correct answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to downvote yet.
Don't be a sore loser.

Answer (score -2):

The answers provided were functional, however they were not what I needed.

The code that gave me what I needed is below.

```
NSMutableArray *storage = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


for (int k = 0; k < [[jsonDeviceData objectAtIndex:0] count]; k++) {

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonDeviceData.count; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < [[jsonDeviceData objectAtIndex:i] count]; j++) {

            if (i == 0) {
                [dict setObject:[[jsonDeviceData objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:k] forKey:@"type1"];
            }
            else if (i == 1) {
                [dict setObject:[[jsonDeviceData objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:k] forKey:@"type2"];
            }
            else if (i == 2) {
                [dict setObject:[[jsonDeviceData objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:k] forKey:@"type3"];
            }
        }
    }
    [storage addObject:dict];
}
```

Comment: You **really** need to learn how to create formatted strings.

Comment: type1, type2, etc are just generic names I used for stackoverflow. In reality the keys will be a specific name.

Comment: You should also use modern syntax such as: `dict[@"type1"] = jsonDeviceData[i][k];`.